# Mockito verifying method calls

Tags: android, mockito, robolectric, roboguice

I'm trying to learn how to use Mockito and i'm hung up on how to go about verifying a method on a certain object was called X amount of times.

I have the following test code

```
verify(record, times(1)).setValue(Mockito.any(String.class),Mockito.any(String.class));
```

and the following piece of production code i'm trying to test

The string[]'s i'm setting up to iterate through

```
protected String[] columnNames = {"_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "name"};
protected ColumnType[] columnTypes = {ColumnType.INTEGER, ColumnType.TIMESTAMP, ColumnType.TIMESTAMP, ColumnType.TEXT};
```

and the production code that's in a loop, iterating through the String[]

```
for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {

            if (columnNames[i].equals("_id")) {
                record.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            } else {

                switch (columnTypes[i]) {
                    case BOOL:
                        record.setValue(columnNames[i], cursor.getInt(i));
                        break;
                    case TEXT:
                        record.setValue(columnNames[i], cursor.getString(i));
                        break;
                    case INTEGER:
                        record.setValue(columnNames[i], cursor.getInt(i));
                        break;
                    case TIMESTAMP:
                        record.setValue(columnNames[i], cursor.getLong(i));
                        break;
                    case LONG:
                        record.setValue(columnNames[i], cursor.getLong(i));
                        break;
                    case DOUBLE:
                        record.setValue(columnNames[i], cursor.getDouble(i));
                        break;
                    default:
                        record.setValue(columnNames[i], "");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

And this is the error i get

> testDataSourceCanFindRecord(com.test.app.DataSourceTest)  Time
>   elapsed: 0.081 sec  <<< FAILURE!
>   org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
>   customer.setValue(, ); Wanted 1 time:
>   -> at com.test.app.DataSourceTest.testDataSourceCanFindRecord(DataSourceTest.java:141)
>   But was 3 times. Undesired invocation:
>   -> at com.test.core.DataSource.cursorToRecord(DataSource.java:210)

I'm expecting record.setValue(String key, String value) to be called once because of the "name" field in the String[]. What's happening is Mockito is registering record.setValue(String key, Long value) as the same thing as record.setValue(String key, String value), which is incorrect. Line 210 is the setValue in the TIMESTAMP case. How can i correct this?

Comment: How do you create the `cursor`? I think it would be much easier to use real `record` object without mocking and verify that the values are correct after setting them from cursor.

Comment: I'm mocking the cursor. I'm mocking everything except the DataSource class that's being tested. I'm still trying to figure out what to mock and what not to

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code for [InvocationMatcher](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/invocation/InvocationMatcher.java), it looks like the logic to check method equality is a little more generous than you might think, and could ignore method overloading in some circumstances.

I'm not 100% sure, but try replacing `any(String.class)` (which accepts [any object](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mockito/Matchers.java#L206) of [any type](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/matchers/Any.java)) with `isA(String.class)`, which will filter out invocations where that parameter is not a String. (`anyString` only checks its type in Mockito 2.0 and beyond.) Counterintuitively, `any(Foo.class)` does not mean "anything as long as it's a Foo", it means "anything". [This is due to change in Mockito 2.0.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/55631479?noredirect=1)

Of course, you could also tighten up your verification so it checks that the key or value is equal to an expected value, but I'm not sure how possible that is in your case.